# Cross-site AJAX - request data from a Tomcat server

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, cross-domain

I have a problem. I currently have a Tomcat server listening on port **8080** of my machine, with a web app running (accessible at **localhost:8080/test-app**). I want this server to deliver dynamically-generated XML files. It's running well in any browser, it does what I want and stuff.

Now, I want to build a web page on another server (I use Aptana's internal server, listening on port **8020**), which would get XML files from the first server.
The problem is, whether I try in Chrome or FireFox, whether I get this page from **localhost:8020/printxml.html** OR right from my filesystem (at **file:///E:/<...>/printxml.html**), I don't receive the data.

Here's my JavaScript code for getting the data (I use jQuery's `$.ajax()` method) :

```
function treatResponse(xml) {
    if(xml == "OK")
        // Deal with the data here
    else
        alert("Error during XML generation");
}

function treatError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("Connection error");
}

function my_login() {

    var props = {
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:8020/printxml.html",
        success : treatResponse,
        error : treatError
    };

    $.ajax(props);

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
I read there should be special headers added server-side to inform that cross-site requests are feasible (using ***Access-Control-Allow-Origin***), but I just can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

try to add http:// before localhost

```
    url : "http://localhost:8020/printxml.html",
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I don't know why I removed it when I wrote my post. But it didn't work, in both ways.